# How to get the functionality of @Autowired JpaRepository by its Class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have a class 'repo' that is found by its class name

```
Class<?> repo = Class.forName("com.example.demo.repository." + modelName + "Repository");
```

where the modelName is a String.

repo.toString() returns

```
interface com.example.demo.repository.LaptopRepository
```

I want to have an ability to use laptopRepository.findAll() methods.
I exactly don't know which modelName I will have.
So I could not use @Autowired annotation outside the method.

Instead I want to use laptopRepository inside the method, which takes the modelName attribute.

```
@GetMapping("/administration")
public String getModelInstances(@RequestParam("modelName")String modelName, Model model) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> repo = Class.forName("com.example.demo.repository." + modelName + "Repository");

    // @Autowired
    // repo repoRepository;

    model.addAttribute("objects", repoRepositories.findAll());
    return "administration";
}
```

Comment: why do you use reflection to fetch this bean ?

Comment: I'm not sure if `findAll` would work, when mixing reflection and `JpaRepository`

Comment: Use the Spring context's getBean() method. But beware: this is a huge security hole: you basically let anybody call findAll() on any of your repositories, potentially giving access to sensitive information, or just crashing your server due to the high number of entities that would be loaded in memory. You at least need to check that the submitted model is among a well-defined list of accepted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Sping application context to get desired repository bean by its type.

1) Autowire context in your controller

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

2) Use it in your method

```
appContext.getBean(Class.forName("com.example.demo.repository." + modelName + "Repository"));
```

Comment: But I how can I access to findAll() method. I want to autowire the repository inside the method, because I don't know beforehand which JpaRepository I will use (The name of the repository to use I am getting from browser in String format).

Comment: Just cast bean to JPARepository interface

Comment: Basically it is better to use some enum for available modelName, because in your approach user can fetch any table that is not secure